# Navigation Experimental choppy transitions

Tags: react-native

I'm having problems getting smooth transitions using RN 0.33 and NavigationExperimental. The problem as I see it is that the rendered scenes are relatively expensive to render and NavigationExperimental keeps both scenes for the transition. I'm wondering what are good strategies for optimizing this process.

What I've done so far is have an 'isAnimating' state in the Navigation component that sets shouldComponentUpdate to false for the scene component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and the dropped frames in the transition were being caused by the fetching of data and the subsequent rendering in componentDidMount of the component I was transitioning to.

You can use InteractionManager in componentDidMount so that your fetching code only runs after any animations or transitions have finished.

For example :

```
  import { InteractionManager } from 'react-native'

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interaction = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {          
      performExpensiveFetch()
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.interaction) this.interaction.cancel()
  }
```